# Why is seaborn superimposing plots?

Tags: python, seaborn, fastapi

The following function is called from a fastapi post request:

```
import seaborn as sns
import os
from random import randint
def make_histogram(data, filepath, destructive = True):
    sns.set()
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    sns.set_palette("husl")
    sns.set_context("paper")
    p = sns.histplot(data, )
    f = p.get_figure()
    
    if destructive and os.path.exists(filepath):
        os.remove(filepath)
        assert not os.path.exists(filepath)
        
    f.figure.savefig(filepath)
```

I was expecting it to trash the plot and recreate it whenever the function is called. Instead it superimposes the plot onto the old plot:[image]

I thought it was modifying the file, so I replaced the filename with a randomly generated id. It still has the same behavior.

That tells me that it's updating the original figure each time the function is called.

I have questions. First, how do I fix it? Second, if it is modifying the figure... how? Why doesn't the figure fall out of scope and get garbage collected?

I have some experience with Jupyter Notebooks, but this is my first time doing anything with web development or traditional IDE.

Comment: You're not creating a figure object yourself, so you're relying on matplotlib's "state machine" interface. Whenever you call a plotting function _without_ specifying a figure object yourself, you're asking it to fetch the "current figure" from the state machine. In your code, that's always the same figure (the one  implicitly on the first plot attempt). See [Matplotlib Application Interfaces (APIs)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces) and [Is calling plt.subplots necessary when using seaborn?](/q/76807352/) for more information.

Comment: What's best practice to declare a new figure?

Comment: Also, does jupyter work differently or am I losing my mind?

Comment: `f.clf()` to clear the figure after saving perhaps.

Comment: "f.clf()",  I like that.